# How can I find nearest neighbors of multiple nodes in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine, nearest-neighbor

So basically I am working on a recommendation system in which a user can choose multiple movies (nodes) and recommendations are given which are similar to all the movies (nodes) selected by the user.

In order to do this, I need to find nearest neighbor of those multiple nodes simultaneously, i.e., result should be close to `node1` and `node2`. How can I do that?

```py
X = [[0., 1., 0.], [1., 0., 1.]]

# consider neighbors to NearestNeighbors() instance
distances, indices = neigh.kneighbors(X)
```

This code returns a 2x2 array, but I just want a single list of indices which are closest to both nodes simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this with a `KDTree`. This uses `scipy`, but the scikit-learn [`KDTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) is similar:

```py
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

tree = KDTree(X)

def midpoint(pnt1, pnt2):
    return np.array([(pnt1[0] + pnt2[0]) / 2, (pnt1[1] + pnt2[1]) / 2])

tree.query_ball_point(midpoint(p1, p2), euclidean(p1, p2) / 2)
```

---

**Explanation:**

(**Left**) Imagine a 2D space of points, and that you want to find a point that is most similar to the two grey points. (**Right**) Now imagine you can draw a length-`D` line that connects your two gray points, giving you a new midpoint `m` and a circle with diameter `D` to search inside.

[image: Two scatter plots. Left: two clusters with a point in the middle. Right: the same plot, but now with a line plus circle connecting two points, with a single point contained inside the circle.]

We can build a `KDTree` on our data and query it to find points near a location. It can be generalized to handle nearest neighbors of a single point, the midpoint of 3+ examples, or "softened" by expanding the query radius

**Full code**:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

X = np.array([[-0.750,-0.766,-0.546,-0.430,-0.0940,0.186,0.422,0.470,0.0780,-0.458,-0.214], [0.531,0.655,0.803,0.659,-0.421,-0.501,-0.477,-0.305,-0.121,0.403,0.183]]).T

tree = KDTree(X)

def midpoint(pnt1, pnt2):
    return np.array([(pnt1[0] + pnt2[0]) / 2, (pnt1[1] + pnt2[1]) / 2])

# Two points from our original data `X`
p1, p2 = X[8], X[9]

# Query the tree with the midpoint and radius (distance / 2) of p1, p2:
most_similar = tree.query_ball_point(midpoint(p1, p2), euclidean(p1, p2) / 2)

print(X[most_similar])   # `most_similar` is a list of indices
# [[-0.214  0.183]]      # Returns a point from our original X
```

Comment: I have to use cosine metrics for distance calculation so KDTree is not a good option for me. But your idea of taking mean of all corresponding features of all nodes to get mid point is very intuitive. It worked for me. Thanks :)